# why does it keeps writing (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int')

Tags: typeerror

```
print('Nous allons transformer des coordonnées sexagécimale en coordonnées décimales, pour cela :')
hemisphere=input('entre tel que hemisphere="x" la lettre 1ère de ton hemisphere :')
degs=input('entre tel que degs=x le nombre de degrès de tes coordonnées :')
minutes=input('entre tel que minutes=x le nombre de minutes de tes coordonnées :')
secondes=input('entre tel que secondes=x le nombre de secondes de tes coordonnées :')

angle=(degs+minutes/60+secondes/3600)

if hemisphere=="n":
    signe="+"
else:
    signe="-"
    
print(signe, angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, your inputs are by default considered as strings. You need to typecast them to int/float for performing division.

This might help:

angle=(int(degs)+int(minutes)/60+int(secondes)/3600)

Answer (score 0):

All the variables `hemisphere`, `degs`, `minutes` and `secondes` are strings. You can't divide a string by a number.

You have to convert the string to numbers first.

```
print('Nous allons transformer des coordonnées sexagécimale en coordonnées décimales, pour cela :')
hemisphere=int(input('entre tel que hemisphere="x" la lettre 1ère de ton hemisphere :'))
degs=int(input('entre tel que degs=x le nombre de degrès de tes coordonnées :'))
minutes=int(input('entre tel que minutes=x le nombre de minutes de tes coordonnées :'))
secondes=int(input('entre tel que secondes=x le nombre de secondes de tes coordonnées :'))

angle=(degs+minutes/60+secondes/3600)

if hemisphere=="n":
    signe="+"
else:
    signe="-"
    
print(signe, angle)
```

Use `float` instead of `int` if you want to enter decimals.

Answer (score 0):

`input` returns you a `string` and you are trying to do `minutes/60` which is `str/int` and as it says, it is an unsupported operand.
just transform your inputs into `int`s:

```py
print('Nous allons transformer des coordonnées sexagécimale en coordonnées décimales, pour cela :')
hemisphere=input('entre tel que hemisphere="x" la lettre 1ère de ton hemisphere :')
degs=int(input('entre tel que degs=x le nombre de degrès de tes coordonnées :'))
minutes=int(input('entre tel que minutes=x le nombre de minutes de tes coordonnées :'))
secondes=int(input('entre tel que secondes=x le nombre de secondes de tes coordonnées :'))

angle=(degs+minutes/60+secondes/3600)

if hemisphere=="n":
    signe="+"
else:
    signe="-"
    
print(signe, angle)
```